# Select from two different tables and group by dates

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm new in databases so I need help. I have two tables:

First table:

```
| Date .........| Diagnostics ................| ID ...............|

| 2015-03-08 ...| Diag1 ......................| 2932 .............|

| 2015-03-09 ...| Diag2 ......................| 2932 .............|
```

Second table:

```
| Date ..........| Evaluation .................|ID ................|

| 2015-03-09 ....| Eval1 ......................| 2932 .............|

| 2015-03-09 ....| Eval2 ......................| 2932 .............|

| 2015-03-10 ....| Eval3 ......................| 2932 .............|
```

And this is what I want - 1 table, rows grouped by dates , 2 columns where id, in this case, is 2932 :

```
| Date ..........| Diagnostics ...............| Evaluation ...............|

| 2015-03-08 ....| Diag1 .....................| ..........................|

| 2015-03-09 ....| Diag2 .....................| Eval1, Eval2 .............|

| 2015-03-10 ....| ...........................| Eval3 ....................|
```

I have tried to do all kind of joins, unions etc. and just couldn't get right result.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using? You'll need some string aggregation as well as a full outer join between the two tables.

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;WITH First_table 
AS (SELECT '2015-03-08' AS [Date],'Diag1' AS Diagnostics, 2932 AS ID
    UNION ALL SELECT '2015-03-09','Diag2', 2932
    )
,Second_table
AS (SELECT '2015-03-09' AS [Date], 'Eval1' AS Evaluation ,2932 AS ID
    UNION ALL SELECT '2015-03-09','Eval2',2932
    UNION ALL SELECT '2015-03-10' ,'Eval3' , 2932)


SELECT
    KT.[Date] AS [Date]
    ,FT.Diagnostics AS [Diagnostics]
    ,STUFF(ST.Evaluation,1,1,'') AS [Evaluation]
FROM
    (
        SELECT [Date] ,[ID]
        FROM First_table
        --GROUP BY [Date] ,[ID]

        UNION 

        SELECT [Date] ,[ID]
        FROM Second_table
        --GROUP BY [Date] ,[ID]
    ) AS KT  --keyTAble
    LEFT JOIN First_table AS FT
        ON kt.[Date] = FT.[Date]
        AND kt.[ID]= FT.[ID]
    OUTER APPLY
        (
            SELECT 
                ',' + Evaluation
            FROM Second_table AS ST
            WHERE 
                KT.[DATE] =ST.[Date]
                AND kT.[ID]= ST.[ID]
            FOR XML PATH('')
        )ST(Evaluation)
```

Comment: I tested both your script and mine and yours runs much faster.

Answer (score 0):

A script to create the temporary tables:

```
 CREATE TABLE #Diagnostics (
    DATE DATE
    ,Diagnostics NVARCHAR(40)
    ,Id INT
    )

CREATE TABLE #Evaluation (
    DATE DATE
    ,Evaluation NVARCHAR(40)
    ,Id INT
    )

INSERT INTO #Diagnostics
VALUES (
    '20150308'
    ,'Diag1'
    ,2932
    )
    ,(
    '20150309'
    ,'Diag2'
    ,2932
    )

INSERT INTO #Evaluation
VALUES (
    '20150309'
    ,'Eval1'
    ,2932
    )
    ,(
    '20150309'
    ,'Eval2'
    ,2932
    )
    ,(
    '20150310'
    ,'Eval3'
    ,2932
    )
```

The select query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT coalesce(d1.DATE, e1.DATE) AS DATE
    ,coalesce((
            SELECT d2.Diagnostics + ','
            FROM #Diagnostics d2
            WHERE d2.DATE = coalesce(d1.DATE, e1.DATE)
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), '') AS Diag
    ,coalesce((
            SELECT e2.Evaluation + ','
            FROM #Evaluation e2
            WHERE e2.DATE = coalesce(d1.DATE, e1.DATE)
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), '') AS Eval
FROM #Diagnostics d1
FULL JOIN #Evaluation e1 ON d1.DATE = e1.DATE
    AND d1.Id = e1.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used temp tables to build an example of your schema so I can test the query. You can substitute your table names in where I have used the temp tables.

```
DECLARE @Evals TABLE
(Date Date
,Eval NVARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @Evals VALUES ('2015-03-09', 'Eval1'), ('2015-03-09', 'Eval2'), ('2015-03-10', 'Eval3')

DECLARE @diags TABLE
(Date Date
,Diags NVARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @diags VALUES ('2015-03-08', 'Diag0'), ('2015-03-09', 'Diag1'), ('2015-03-09', 'Diag2'), ('2015-03-10', 'Diag3')


SELECT  a.Date, 
        (
            SELECT (d.Diags + ',')
            FROM    @diags AS d
            WHERE   d.Date = a.Date
            FOR XML PATH('')
        ) AS Diagnostics,
        (
            SELECT (e.Eval + ',')
            FROM    @Evals AS e
            WHERE   e.Date = a.Date
            FOR XML PATH('')
        ) AS Evaluation

FROM (  
        SELECT Date 
        FROM @Evals 
        UNION 
        SELECT Date 
        FROM @diags) AS a

GROUP BY a.Date
```